# SQL Server : IF THEN ELSE in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I have a stored procedure that I pass an integer parameters to (`@truncate`).
What I want is this.

```
if @truncate = 1
then 
   truncate some_table 
   do something else
else 
   do only the "do something else" (before the else) without truncating the table..
```

The "do something else" part of the code is quite long.. How do I do this without repeating the "do something else" code and making the stored procedure longer than necessary?

Comment: Your logic works fine. If you really want it to be shorter, maybe you could create a different store procedure for "do something else" and call the stored procedure in this stored procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you only need an `IF` to cover the truncation, and the other logic should always execute.  So just remove the `ELSE` condition and place that logic after the `IF`.

```
if @truncate = 1
begin 
    truncate some_table
end

do something else   -- always do this
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the stored procedure to execute "do something else" if the first statement is not executed.

Comment: @CookieMonster I disagree.  The OP seems to want to avoid repeating a large swath of code which currently appears in two places.

Comment: Ah.. with the edit from Aaron.. this works a treat.. I just couldn't see it.. thank you